# In MonetDB, can I obtain the database name via SQL commands?

Tags: sql, reflection, database, monetdb

Does MonetDB make the current DB name (i.e. not the DBMS hostname, but the DB, or set of tables, that you connect to) available via SQL queries to some of the system table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the env() table-producing function also has the db name, in my case 'acs'.

```
sql>select value from env() where name='gdk_dbname';
+-------+
| value |
+=======+
| acs   |
+-------+
```

Comment: you know a lot of awesome things